# how to print a value inside the foreach loop?

Tags: php

```
$id = 123;

$my_var[$id]["lname"] = "Smith";
$my_var[$id]["fname"] = "John";

foreach ($my_var as $rec) {
    print "Last Name: " . $rec["lname"]. "\n";
    print "First Name: " . $rec["fname"]. "\n";

    // print "ID: " . $id . "\n";      // THIS WORKS BUT NOT WHAT I WANT
    print "ID: " . $rec[$id] . "\n";     // DOESNOT WORK
}
```

How would I print the value of $id inside the foreach() loop WITHOUT using $id directly?

Comment: Once Code Slave met Manual Slave, they became a pair for life.

Answer (score 3):

Specify key and value in the `foreach` loop. I'm calling it `$key` here, because you already used `$id`, but you might as well recycle that name.

```
foreach ($my_var as $key => $rec)
{
   print "Last Name: " . $rec["lname"]. "\n";
   print "First Name: " . $rec["fname"]. "\n";

   print "ID: " . $key . "\n";   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In PHP you can access the key in your associative array as per the below:

```
$id = 123;

$my_var[$id]["lname"] = "Smith";
$my_var[$id]["fname"] = "John";

foreach ($my_var as $key => $rec) {
    print "Last Name: " . $rec["lname"]. "\n";
    print "First Name: " . $rec["fname"]. "\n";

    print "ID: " . $key . "\n";     // Is your ID
}
```